# how to recover oracle database using contro.dbf,sysaux.dbf?

Tags: oracle

I had a problem while accessing oracle database ,so then i copied the old oraclexe folder into a new drive.Later I have installed the oracle 10g express edition.While copying only two files goit copied i.e., control.dbf,sysaux.dbf.Can anyone tell me whether I can recover the database from these two files ? If yes,kindly tell the procedure to recover ?

Comment: Do you have backup?Logical/Physical? If yes then you may recover it using these backups.

Comment: No backup is available i have copied the entire folder of oracle installation folder.I am now left with control.dbf,sysaux.dbf.Is it possible to recover with these two files ??